# Solve the equation $\sqrt[8]{x^5}+2\sqrt{x}=3\sqrt[4]{x^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\sqrt[8]{x^5}+2\sqrt{x}=3\sqrt[4]{x^3}$$ We first have $D_x:x\ge0$ as all roots are with even indices.

I decided to write all the roots with index $8$. Is this really a good idea? Or is it better to use powers?

So now the equation is $$\sqrt[8]{x^5}+2\sqrt[8]{x^4}=3\sqrt[8]{x^6}$$ I don't really see anything from here that can work.

Comment: Of course $x=0$ is a solution. So let $x\neq 0$ and divide by $\sqrt[8]{x^4}$.

Comment: Writing everything as $8^{th}$ roots is good. In addition to Dietrich's comment, I would recommend writing everything as exponents rather than roots. Try a substitution $u=x^{1/8}$ to get away from fractional powers (you'll have to back substitute afterward). Converting everything to $8^{th}$ roots guarantees a common denominator after converting to fractional powers. These steps can be done before or after applying Dietrich's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have arrived at: $$x^{\frac58}+2x^{\frac48}=3x^{\frac68}$$
Now let $y=x^{\frac18}$ to get: $$y^5+2y^4=3y^6$$
Which means $y=0$ or $y+2=3y^2$
You should be able to solve from here, if any problem occurs, check below.

> You'll get $y=0,1,-\frac23$
> $x^{\frac18}$ can't be negative.
> Answer: $x=0,1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $x=t^8$ so we have $$t^5+2t^4=t^6$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=t^8$, so $$t^5+2t^4=3t^6$$$$\implies (3t^2-t-2)(t^4)=0$$ Now $t^4=0\implies t=0\implies x=0$ is a solution.

Other values for $t$ are $t=1, t=-\dfrac23$ so that $x=1, x=\left(\dfrac23\right)^8$ are the other solutions. But the latter does not satisfy the original equation.